# Does client certificate authentication demand more server-side entropy?

Tags: tls, certificates, client-side, entropy

We have a secure web service running Apache that requires client certificates for access. This service has a problem with running out of entropy. We have several other sites that use TLS that get similar amounts of traffic but have never had any problem with a lack of entropy.

I am wondering if requiring a client certificate requires more entropy. Looking at the TLS specification I don't see where the client providing a certificate places more demand on the server-side entropy source. Maybe our problem has nothing to do with client certificates, but I would like to eliminate that as a problem source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you "run out of entropy", then you are using `/dev/random`, and you should not. You should use `/dev/urandom`. The whole concept of "running out of entropy" is based on a flawed metaphor in which randomness is viewed as a kind of gasoline. That's just wrong. *Recent* versions of the [man page of `/dev/random`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/random.4.html) (on Linux) are less terrible than what they used to be, and now recommend the right thing, which is to use `/dev/urandom`.

(When I say "you" it might be "the software you use". Regardless, *someone* is doing a stupid thing, and that stupid thing probably involves `/dev/random`.)

In any case, certificate validation entails *verifying* digital signatures, and there is no need of any kind of randomness for that (at least with "normal" signature algorithms like RSA, DSA or ECDSA).

**Edit:** actually, while the basic certificate validation uses no randomness at all, the checks for revocation status entail contacting external servers to download CRL or OCSP responses, so that's network traffic which may stall and thus display symptoms similar to a blocked read on `/dev/random`. And the protocol to obtain an OCSP response *may* include a random nonce included by the requester (here, the server), so it is conceivable that a read on `/dev/random` still lurks in that code. That's a bit far fetched.

Comment: We had already moved to `/dev/urandom` but our security policy frowns on that for applications that are supposed to be "highly-secure".

Comment: Then it's time to update your security policy, @rlandster, as Tom is exactly right that you should be using `/dev/urandom`, not `/dev/random`.

Comment: You might want to consider adding a RNG/PRNG source. There are expensive hardware devices for this. A cheap software-only solution that seems to work well (and is supposed to be secure) is the terribly-named [HAVEGED](http://freecode.com/projects/haveged)

Comment: @Tom - re your hypothesis on CRL/OCSP, I'm not sure but I imagine the server providing those are themselves using SSL? In that case, it's not purely network traffic, but SSL traffic. Agree this probably is quite far fetched.

Comment: @YoavAner: ah yes, it is conceivable. I have actually seen it done (CRL publication with an `https://` URL) even though it makes little sense.

Comment: @TomLeek why doesn't it make sense? couldn't an attacker potentially intercept the CRL response to hide/block you from knowing a particular certificate expired?

Comment: @YoavAner: a CRL is public data; and it is signed. Whoever uses a CRL must first verify the signature on it, relatively to the CA key. Like certificates and OCSP responses, CRL embed their own security, precisely so that the way they are transported is of no consequence. The best an attacker can do is block the download (i.e. cuts the wire), and he can do that _anyway_, SSL or no SSL.

Comment: That makes sense. Have to do some reading on CRL/OCSP. Haven't looked at it in a while. Thanks @TomLeek